# R regex get year out of vector

Tags: r, regex

Ok regex is officially the bane of my existence.

I need a sub expression to get the year as a separate character vector in R please:

```
vector <- c("Hello_world_1999_otherstuff.file", "Hello_2010_world_otherstuff.file", "2015_hello_world_help_me_thanks!.file")

vector.desired <- c("1999", "2010", "2015")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use : **\d{4}**

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qu2kWe/1/)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are no other numbers, in particular with more than four digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
libray(stringr)
str_extract(vector, "\\d{4}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub` from base R:

```
vector <- c("Hello_world_1999_otherstuff.file", "Hello_2010_world_otherstuff.file", "2015_hello_world_help_me_thanks!.file")
years <- sub(".*(?:^|_)(\\d{4})(?:_|$).*", "\\1", vector)

years
[1] "1999" "2010" "2015"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

using base r

```
 regmatches(vector,regexpr("\\d{4}",vector))
[1] "1999" "2010" "2015"
```

To use look arounds in case there are other values before the year, you can use:

```
 regmatches(vector,regexpr("(?<=^|_)\\d{4}(?=_|$)",vector,perl = T))
[1] "1999" "2010" "2015" "1999"
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just checked out. the code i wrote is using `regexpr` and not `gregexpr` Thus it will only pick the first 4digit number form the string. Thus in the example you gave it will pick `1999` and not `1234`. Thanks

Comment: True true. I see what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: The look around are exactly similar to yours.